# Right align the rowname_col in gt

Tags: r, gt

I'd like to right align the `rowname_col` but it doesn't look like you can apply `cols_align` to rownames?

```
tibble(
  one = c("Long names", "Other Name", "Name | Name"),
  two = 1:3
) %>% gt(rowname_col = "one") %>%
  cols_align(align = "right", columns = vars(one))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right align the rowname column like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

tibble(
  one = c("Long names", "Other Name", "Name | Name"),
  two = 1:3
) %>% gt(rowname_col = "one") %>%
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_text(align = "right")
    ),
    locations = cells_stub(rows = TRUE)
  )
```

[image]